# jquery <input type="text" name="quantity[1]" /> get by name

Tags: jquery

How can I do something like this:

Given:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[1]" />

if ($("#item_kit_items").find('input[name=quantity[1]').length ==1)
{
    alert('exists');
}
```

(The above doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the `[]` characters. Also, you were missing the closing bracket:

```
$("#item_kit_items").find('input[name=quantity\\[1\\]]')
```

Alternatively, you can quote the name:

```
$("#item_kit_items").find('input[name="quantity[1]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote it and close the brace.

```
if ($("#item_kit_items").find("input[name='quantity[1]']").length == 1)
```